# Databricks Autoloader File Notification service

Tags: databricks, databricks-autoloader

I have setup Autoloader to read notification from storage queue for new files upload into the Azure data lake gen2.
I am receiving the new file notification from Azure queue storage but Data bricks process is not creating the right mount path to read the files

e.g
I have created a mount path in initialization
abfss://container@storageaaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/",mount_point = "/mnt/test/"

if I upload a file to container/landing-zone path then the databrick's autoloader should be reading from path dbfs:/mnt/test/landing-zone/
Instead autoloader is reading from dbfs:/mnt/testlanding-zone/ a leading slash is getting removed from the path in case of autoloader